# SQL - Output a column if another column has max value

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table like the below:

```
CustID   Date         Comments
A        JAN 1        abc    
A        JAN 5        def    
B        JAN 2        ttt    
B        JAN 7        hhh    
B        JAN 10       hhh
```

I need to add a column to this table to show the Comments column for the row with the min date for each customer. Sample output below.

```
CustID   Date         Comments  NewCol
A        JAN 1        abc       abc    
A        JAN 5        def       abc 
B        JAN 9        ttt       hhh   
B        JAN 7        hgg       hhh    
B        JAN 3        hhh       hhh
```

I'm using Teradata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `FIRST_VALUE()` (see [here](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_112A/Ordered_Analytical_Functions.093.068.html#ww13179023)):

```
select t.*,
       first_value(Comments) over (partition by CustId order by Date) as newCol
from table t;
```